# Remove multiple array from other array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Have 2 array like this

```
arr = ["9138172", "9138214", "9138238"]
array = ["9138172", "9138238"]
```

how can I remove values in `array` from `arr`?
I want to obtain

```
arr = ["9138214"]
```

Maybe I can use `splice()` ?

Comment: what if a value is in `array` but not in `arr`?

Comment: This is a duplicate of like a thousand or more other questions. Also, no attempt was made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.forEach()` to loop over to the array of items and then check that each item exist in `array` array. If so use `splice()`. Use simple function and `indexOf()` as it will work in old browsers and also in IE.

```js
var arr = ["9138172", "9138214", "9138238"];
var array = ["9138172", "91382142"];
var i = arr.length;
while (i--) {
  if (array.indexOf(arr[i]) !== -1) {
    arr.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: @hoon1 you can tick mark the answer if it was helpful to you.

Comment: btw if arr and array have a same value, why arr not have an empty array ?

Comment: @hoon1 in that case use a `while` loop. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for that.

Here is an example:

```js
var arr = ["9138172", "9138214", "9138238"];
var array = ["9138172", "9138238"];

arr = arr.filter(e => !array.includes(e));

console.log(arr)
```

The code above just filters the `arr` array and keeps only elements that are not present in the `array`. The [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function that I've used works on these arrays because they contain strings, if you're dealing with objects, you need to find some other way of checking if `array` contains the element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lodash, this can be easily done by the difference function:

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#difference

```
import {difference} from 'lodash';


arr = ["9138172", "9138214", "9138238"]
array = ["9138172", "9138238"]

console.log(difference(arr, array));
```